# I had issue in below mention program to assign a value to the pointer.String concatenation Program( *s1=*s2)

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-concatenation

While running below code i am getting error to assign the value to the s1 pointer

```
#include<stdio.h>

void concat(char*, char*);

//Main Program
void main(void)
{
    char str1[25], str2[25];
    printf("\nEnter First String:");
    gets(str1);
    printf("\nEnter Second String:");
    gets(str2);
    //Function call
    concat(str1, str2);
    printf("\nConcatenated String is %s", str1);
}

void concat(char *s1, char *s2) {
    // Checking Null character
    while (*s1 != '\0')
        s1++;
    //Checking Null character
    while (*s2 != '\0')
    {
        *s1 = *s2; //<-- Getting error in this line        
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    *s1 = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What is your error ? compilation error ? runtime error ? I have no error.

Comment: Is this your verbatim code? You're missing a pair of braces (`{}`) after the first `while` loop! And a semicolon after `s1++`.

Comment: I think it is just an indentation error because he's missing the ';' after `s1++`

Comment: @AntiClimacus Unlikely in a function called `concat`.

Comment: I am stranger here .so i don't know how to paste the code .Now i am typed it correctly.I have an error that access violation

Comment: THere is the preview window and all that formatting help. Tripped a warning with that wall of code?

Comment: _'I am stranger here'_ No, you're a user as anybody else here. Maybe you want to read the arcticles provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help) first, before posting questions.

Comment: What Input causes the error?

Comment: You can use `edit` to update your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are getting access voilation....

The problem is that your buffers are probably overflowing and you have no length check in your code...

The buffers you have allocated are only 25 bytes long

```
char str1[25], str2[25];
```

so to intruduce a length check, add an extra parameter to concat which tells how long the output buffer is, like this

```
void concat(char *s1, char *s2, int len){
    // Checking Null character
    while (*s1 != '\0' && len > 0)
        s1++, len--;
    //Checking Null character
    while (*s2 != '\0' && len > 0)
    {
        *s1 = *s2; //<-- Getting error in this line        
        s1++;
        s2++;
        len--;
    }
    if (len > 0) // only set the null terminator if we have space
       *s1 = '\0';
}
```

an then call it as this

```
concat(str1, str2, 25);
```

An then also read the man page for [strncat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat)

Answer (score 1):

because you are concatting str2 onto the end of str1, str1 needs to be large enough to hold the complete string, so you are problably overrunning str1, try

```
   char str1[25+25], str2[25];
```

Comment: I need to use pointer.

Comment: @user3578340 It has nothing to do with whether to use pointers or not. It's about the allocation of memory to store the concatenated string in.

Answer (score 0):

The missing semi-colon after

```
  while(*s1!='\0')                                // Checking Null character
    s1++
```

is your problem, as the code is, the 2nd while loop will be executed everytime there is a character in s1.

Comment: No that is not an issue .While i am assigning value to *s1=*s2 i am getting access violation error

Comment: in the code you __originally__ posted it WOULD have been an issue